# Gatsby don't change state with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby, tailwind-css

I created a  component for my gatsby site. 
And I wanted to write a simply toggle functionality for it:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import './css/header.css'

function clicker(state) {
   console.log(state);
}

const header = () => {

const [isExpanded, toggleExpansion] = useState(false)

return (

    <div>
        <nav className="main-nav">
            <div className={'container container-wide'}>

                {/* responsive toggle */}
                <div className="block lg:hidden">
                    <button onClick={() => clicker(!isExpanded)}
                        className="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
                        <svg className="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title>
                            <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>

                {/* Main Menu*/}
                <div className={`${isExpanded ? `block` : `hidden`} w-full lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto justify-end`}  >
                    <div className="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
                        <a href="#responsive-header"
                            className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-lightest hover:text-white mx-6">
                            Docs
                            </a>
                        <a href="#responsive-header"
                            className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-lightest hover:text-white mx-6">
                            Examples
                            </a>
                        <a href="#responsive-header"
                            className="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-lightest hover:text-white mx-6">
                            Blog
                            </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
)
```

}

export default header;

The problem is: the state seems to be there.
When I click the link the clicker(state) function gives back, 
whatever the initial state is.

But the toggleExpansion function does simple not work or trigger. 
Or ... the component does not render according to the new state ..

I dont know. 
Can somebody help?

When I use a class component it works fine - can someone tell my why?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you are doing the you should capitalize the name of your component as recommended in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) . The second thing is you should move your event handler logic into your Header component since it belongs to that component.
Inorder to trigger the state change fix the code in your event handler as shown in code below.

From your code I also see that you might also be missing another important concept about React Hooks. Note that inside any particular render, props and state forever stay the same and that each render has its own event handlers. Your event handlers only ***'see'***  or ***'close over(see closures)'*** the values of state and props for its particular render. Therefore console logging the state inside your event handler will always give you the state for the particular render. The call to setToggleExpansion only calls your function component again with the updated state and its own event handlers.

Hope that helps.

```
const Header = () => {

  const [isExpanded, setToggleExpansion] = useState(false)

  // event handler
  function clicker() {
   console.log(isExpanded);            // logs false for the initial render
   setToggleExpansion(prev => !prev);
   console.log(isExpanded);            // logs false for the initial render
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={clicker}
     //...
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: This was the mistake. The capital letter. Thank u.

Comment: It turned out that the working one was in the cache. Nothing worked. Even the example code with the counter on the react.js site was not working. The state just dont update. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
It seems something break my site. But the console dont show anything.

Answer (score 1):

First your component name should start with capital letter as [React recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) Just change it to `Header`

Second, change your toggle function like this:

```js
const Header = () => {
  const [isExpanded, toggleExpansion] = useState(false)

  return (
    <button onClick={() => toggleExpansion(!isExpanded)}
     //...
    </button>
  )
}
```

And to use it just use `&&` [logical operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) like this:

```js
{ 
   isExpanded && ( <div> ... </div> ) 
}
```

[image: Edit long-star-0ob0w]